# Discord Default Profile Background Color

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, bots, discord.net

In the Discord api I have the accent color which is the background color of the user. But this value returns null when color is default. How do I pull the default color?

Comment: Can you show your code so far

Answer (score 0):

This is an API limitation. This information is only available with `bot.fetch_user` as stated in [The Documetation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.User.accent_color)

Edit:
You were asking help with discord API, I realized that later. But that shouldn't cause an issue. It worked fine for me when I used `requests` module of python and sent a `GET` request to the `/users/{userid}` endpoint with Bot authorization token

Here is my code and output respectively:

```py
import requests
import pprint

TOKEN = "My Bot Token"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {TOKEN}"}
userid = 914596711010287698
req = requests.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/users/{userid}", headers=headers)
pprint.pprint(req.json())
```

```json
{'accent_color': 9279926,
 'avatar': 'e9cefd0c155b6c84fe76ab6c9e7e4607',
 'banner': None,
 'banner_color': '#8d99b6',
 'discriminator': '1328',
 'id': '914596711010287698',
 'public_flags': 128,
 'username': 'Rose'}
```

just incase, `pprint` is an `in-built` module which is short for `PrettyPrint`, and it is used exactly for as the name suggests, printing json with readable indents and spacing.

Comment: Color default is returning null

Answer (score -1):

let avatarUrl = user.displayAvatarURL()